# Does $C^0$ convergence imply "eventually homotopic"?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Consider a sequence of continuous mappings $f_n:M\to N$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, where $M$ and $N$ are compact smooth manifolds, or in general, compact and Hausdorff metric spaces.

Suppose that $f_n \to f$ in the $C^0$ topology, which in this case reduces simply to uniform convergence. Is it true that $f_n$ is homotopic to $f$ for every $n$ sufficiently large?

I believe that this is true because of the following: in our case, the property of two mappings $f$ and $g$ being homotopic is equivalent to being in the same path-connected component of the function space $C(M,N)$ in the $C^0$ topology, i.e., just the uniform convergence topology. And, if $f_n\to f$ in this topology, I believe it should be contained in the path connected component of $f$ for sufficiently large $n$ (but I don't know how to prove it).

My goal is to use this fact to argue that $deg(f_n) = deg(f)$ for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For manifolds (or more generally [absolute neighborhood retracts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retraction_(topology)) of euclidean spaces) consider embedding $N\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. Next pick [a tubular neighborhood](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Tubular_neighbourhood) $U$ of $N$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$. There is a smooth retraction $r:U\rightarrow N$ and $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ consider the homotopy $h_n:[0,1]\times M\rightarrow  \mathbb{R}^n$ given by formula
$$h_n(t,m) = tf(m) + (1 - t)f_n(m)$$
Since $\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges uniformly to $f$, we derive that
$$h_n([0,1]\times M)\subseteq U$$
for sufficiently large $n$. Then $H = r\cdot h_n:[0,1]\times M\rightarrow N$ is a homotopy between $f_n$ and $f$.

In the case of general compact metric spaces the result does not hold. For this pick
$$M = pt,\,N = \{0\}\cup \bigg\{\frac{1}{n}\,|\,n\in \mathbb{N}\bigg\}$$
and consider continuous maps $f_n(pt) = \frac{1}{n}$ and $f(pt) = 0$. Then $f_n\rightarrow f$ uniformly, but $f_n$ are $f$ are never homotopic.

Comment: What a nice counter example for the general case! What do you think its the most general context this holds? The idea of using tubular neighborhoods was amazing, but I imagine that there must be a "more topological" condition on the metric spaces that could be used in general to get this result.

Comment: The most reasonable class, that comes to my mind, is the class of absolute neighborhood retracts of euclidean spaces. This is a very large class of topological spaces. I added a link, if you are interested.